# How to init materialize sidenav in Angular 5 project?

Tags: angular, materialize

I have angular project. Included materialize css and js using cdn. Can't init sidenav using script tag in index.html since navbar is one of component in my project. So what's best way to include materialize css in angular projects(for production) and how ro init the materlize components like sidenav, Carousel etc.

```
  var elem = document.querySelector('.sidenav');
  var instance = M.Sidenav.init(elem, options);
```

Above code is used to initialise sidenav while using JavaScript.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What have you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: Can you give more specifics like code or something?

Comment: Added code which is used in JavaScript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of 'AfterViewInit' of angular to initialize elements. In your 'ts' file, implement 'AfterViewInit' and override ngAfterViewInit() method. Then write your initialization code inside setTimeout() function inside ngAfterViewInit().

```
export class NameComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  ....

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout( function() {
      var elem = document.querySelector('.sidenav');
      var instance = M.Sidenav.init(elem, options);
    }, 0)
  }

  .....

}
```

Comment: Also, if you are getting the following error: 

`Cannot find name 'M'.`

add `declare const M;` underneath your imports

Comment: Thank you @DarrylMendonez for mentioning it. But I import materialize to make use of it. - `import * as M from 'materialize-css'`

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend you use the official Angular Material package to use material design in your Angular5 project. It has a great integration with angular and you don't need any javascript setup in your `index.html`.

You can learn more in the Angular Material [site](https://material.angular.io/) with a very clear setup guide and a good documentation.

Regarding your question, with Angular Material you can get a working sidenav with this:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened>Sidenav content</mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>Main content</mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Just remember to correctly import the sidenav module in your `app.module.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the materialize library in an angular 5 project, I highly recommend you have a look at [angular2-materialize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize), as opposed to simply importing JS and CSS from a CDN.

You simply import the module in your `app.module` and have access to all the materialize elements.